# jQuery GetJSON Security Issues. Copying URL and pasting in the browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, security

I am using the jQuery GetJSON call in my ASP page. It is something like the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl/myPage.aspx?callback=BookARoom,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

This will actually end up in a room being booked in my system, but the issue is that if a user copies this URL and pastes it in a browser, the room would get booked. Since he already has the session, I can't differentiate it in the ASP Pages. How can I prevent this?

Comment: How exactly is this a security problem? If there's anything that needs to be validated you need to to it server-side anyway. So you shouldn't have to care if the user crafted the request manually or if it actually came from your javascript.

Comment: Consider that I send you a link <click here> and it auto-books a room since you're logged in (or worse, <img src ="www.mywebsite.com/myUrl/myPage.aspx?callback=BookARoom" />... then you don't even know it has happened!).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

First problem: `GET` requests are supposed to be safe.  There are lots of things that can trigger a `GET` request.  If you are changing state based on a `GET` request, your code is dangerously broken.  Use `POST`.

Secondly, other websites can cause your user to make requests to your website.  This is known as [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF).  The typical solution is to require a nonce with each request.  Because the nonce is unknown to the other website, they can no longer forge requests.  The link I provided will give you further reading on alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your average user from doing it, require it to use a POST instead of GET as the HTTP verb (the requirement must be set server side) and type: "POST" should be used in your ajax call.

To prevent your "advanced" user from spoofing it, the short answer is: you can't. There are ways around anything that you can come up with. Consider using a CSRF token to prevent others from embedding the link in another website.